# Using Waypoints.js inside an AngularJS view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-waypoints

I am trying to use Waypoints inside a scrollable AngularJS view, however it's not working. I am trying to use ui.utils jQuery Passthrough but nothing happens. Here's what I have so far:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="nav-menu">
        <...>
    </div>


    <div id="main" class="main">
        <div ng-view></div> 
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I am using the following template for the view:

```
<div class="fullScreenImage"></div>
<div ui-jq="waypoint" ui-options="test">test</div>
```

and my controller looks something like this:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope',
 function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = function(){
       alert('You have scrolled to an entry.');
}}]);
```

My **main** element is scrollable but the window is not. Setting passthrough to the main div will trigger the test function, however I need it inside the template. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Providing a JSFiddle or plunkr would be helpful.

But I suppose the issue is because the template is inside `ngView`.

As the content of the template is placed inside the `ngView` via XHR, the waypoints needs to be refreshed as discussed in the link http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#doc-refresh

An Angular directive will be more effective IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with waypoints nested in ng-views as well.

My solution was just to wait till after the view had loaded to bind the waypoints, for this you can use `$viewContentLoaded`.

E.g.

```
myApp.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){

        var waypoint = new Waypoint({
            element: document.getElementById('waypoint'),
            handler: function(direction) {
                console.log('Scrolled to waypoint!')
            }
        })
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It's also possible to delay the binding with `$timeout` e.g `$timeout(addWaypoints());`.